# Given a range, getting all dates within that range in Scala

Tags: scala, date, loops

I need to make a function in scala that, given a range of dates, gives me a list of the range.
I am relatively new in Scala and I am not able to figure out how to write the right 'for' loop for the same. This is what I have done so far:

```
def calculateDates(from: LocalDate, until: LocalDate): Seq[LocalDate] = {
  var dateArray = []
  //for (LocalDate date <- from; !date.isAfter(to); date <- date.plusDays(1)) 
  for(date <- from to until)
  {
        dateArray :+ date
  }
  return dateArray 
}
```

I do not know how to iterate over the range.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
val numberOfDays = Days.daysBetween(from, until).getDays()
for (f<- 0 to numberOfDays) yield from.plusDays(f)
```

Comment: Is 'Days' a class in scala?

Comment: it's a class in joda-time which you seem to be using:
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html

Answer (score 31):

If you happen to use the Java 1.8 `DateTime` API (or its 1.7 backport threeten), then you could write

```
def between(fromDate: LocalDate, toDate: LocalDate) = {
    fromDate.toEpochDay.until(toDate.toEpochDay).map(LocalDate.ofEpochDay)
}
```

Comment: this is not including todate? I have a scenerio i want to list from and todate both?

Comment: I'm guessing you can use `.to` instead of `.until` (this should be standard Scala), but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
def dateRange(start: DateTime, end: DateTime, step: Period): Iterator[DateTime] =
Iterator.iterate(start)(_.plus(step)).takeWhile(!_.isAfter(end))
```

To generate every date, you can set the step to 1 day like

```
val range = dateRange(
<yourstartdate>,
<yourenddate>,
Period.days(1))
```

Comment: This may be a poor solution depending on needs because with start = new DateTime(2015, 1, 30, 0, 0), end = new DateTime(2015, 5, 2, 0, 0), step = Period.months(1) it yields "2015-01-30", "2015-02-28", "2015-03-28", "2015-04-28", not "2015-01-30", "2015-02-28", "2015-03-30", "2015-04-30"

Answer (score 6):

When running `Scala` on `Java 9+`, we can take advantage of the new [`java.time.LocalDate::datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil-java.time.LocalDate-):

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import collection.JavaConverters._

// val start = LocalDate.of(2018, 9, 24)
// val end   = LocalDate.of(2018, 9, 28)
start.datesUntil(end).iterator.asScala.toList
// List[LocalDate] = List(2018-09-24, 2018-09-25, 2018-09-26, 2018-09-27)
```

And to include the last date within the range:

```
start.datesUntil(end.plusDays(1)).iterator.asScala.toList
// List[LocalDate] = List(2018-09-24, 2018-09-25, 2018-09-26, 2018-09-27, 2018-09-28)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Lamma Date](http://lamma.io)

```
$ scala -cp lamma_2.11-1.1.2.jar 
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import io.lamma.Date
import io.lamma.Date

scala> Date(2015, 7, 7) to Date(2015, 7, 10) foreach println 
Date(2015,7,7)
Date(2015,7,8)
Date(2015,7,9)
Date(2015,7,10)
```

This `DateRange` is evaluated in a lazy way. Feel free to construct a date range of 5000 years. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since Scala is a functional, go with a recursion:

```
def calculateDates(from: LocalDate, until: LocalDate): Seq[LocalDate] = {
    if from.compareTo(until) > 1
        return[]
    else
        return from :: calculateDates(from.plusDays(1), until)
}
```