# 'forward reference extends over definition of variable dateList' while generating daterange

Tags: scala, date, recursion

I am trying to make an List of all dates between 2 given dates in scala. This is the program that I have written:

```
object testingscala
{
    def main(args: Array[String]) 
    {
       println(calculateDates(LocalDate.of(2014,1,1), LocalDate.of(2014,2,5)))
    }
    def calculateDates(from: LocalDate, until: LocalDate): List[LocalDate] = 
   {
        var arr = List[LocalDate]()
        var dateList = calculateDatesRecur(from, until) // forward reference extends over definition of variable 
 dateList
        def calculateDatesRecur(from: LocalDate, until: LocalDate): List[LocalDate] =
        {
            if (from.compareTo(until) > 1) {return arr}
            else
            { arr = arr :+ from; calculateDatesRecur(from.plusDays(1), until)}
        }
        return dateList

   }

}
```

I am relatively new at Scala so I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the implementation.
The function just takes two parameters and prints out all the dates between the two dates. I have used recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because Scala have no literal syntax for arrays/lists. You have to go with

```
 var arr = List.empty[LocalDate]
```

or

```
 var arr = List[LocalDate]()
```

Not that **list isn't array** in scala.

Although you haven't asked, I do believe this code could be written in a much more concise way:

```
object testingscala extends App
{
    type LD = LocalDate
    println(calculateDatesRecur(LocalDate.of(2014,1,1), LocalDate.of(2014,2,5)))

    @annotation.tailrec
    def calculateDatesRecur(from: LD, until: LD, xs: List[LD] = List.empty[LD]): List[LD] = 
      if (from.compareTo(until) > 1) xs.reverse
      else calculateDatesRecur(from.plusDays(1), until, from::xs)
}
```

Haven't tested it though.

**And answering your comment:**

swap recursive function and dateList variable, so function definition comes first.

```
...
def calculateDatesRecur(from: LocalDate, until: LocalDate): List[LocalDate] =
{
  if (from.compareTo(until) > 1) {return arr}
  else
  { arr = arr :+ from; calculateDatesRecur(from.plusDays(1), until)}
}
var dateList = calculateDatesRecur(from, until)
...
```

you're trying to assign function result, but since it is used like a nested function it is not known apriory so compiler don't know what to set to dateList (actually it do knows, but prevents you from doing nasty things).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I edited it. But it shows an error in the declaration of datelist variable.What do you suppose forward reference means?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Given a range, getting all dates within that range in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426807/given-a-range-getting-all-dates-within-that-range-in-scala/24169524#24169524)

With [Lamma Date](http://lamma.io) simply `(2014, 5, 5) to (2014, 5, 10) foreach println`